# Convert Continuous Dataframe to Categorical

Tags: r, categorical-data, continuous

I know how to convert individual continuous variables of a dataframe into categorical variables. But how can this be done for an entire dataframe at once? It seems there should be some simple way to do this but I am not seeing it. My dataframe has 34 rows and 65 variables and all variables take either a 0, 1 or 2 value. I want each value to be categorical. And the meaning of a 0, 1 or 2 is the same across all variables. Below is some R code to recreate a small subset of the data:

```
continuous<-data.frame(c(0,1,0,2),c(2,2,0,0),c(1,0,1,0),c(2,1,0,0))
colnames(continuous)<-c('A','B','C','D')
continuous$A<-as.factor(continuous$A) #This works, for individual variables
continuous<-as.factor(continuous) #This throws an error for the whole dataframe
```

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this. Although you'd have to reshape it with `gather` first, then make your values the factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think you can use lapply for this...

```
continuous<-data.frame(c(0,1,0,2),c(2,2,0,0),c(1,0,1,0),c(2,1,0,0))
colnames(continuous)<-c('A','B','C','D')
c2 <- lapply(continuous, as.factor)
str(c2)
List of 4
 $ A: Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","2": 1 2 1 3
 $ B: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","2": 2 2 1 1
 $ C: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 2 1
 $ D: Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","2": 3 2 1 1
```

though likely you want a data frame or tibble instead of a list so

```
c2 <- data.frame(lapply(continuous, as.factor))
```